# rails, how to stub :user_id in session with mocha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, tdd, rspec-rails, mocha.js

How would I stub `:user_id` in a `session` using mocha framework with Spec test ?

I tried the following:

> session.stubs(:user_id).returns(1)
>
> session.stub!(:user_id).and_return(1)
>
> session.expects(:[]).with(has_entries('user_id' => 1))

but I got nil for session[:user_id] in the above tries!

All examples shows how to stub an object, but session is a hash array, how would I stub or mock a certain key like :user_id, or :page_id .. etc in session ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a new session instance on every request, so you have to stub every single one.

```
?> session.class
=> ActionController::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash
```

So what you have to stub is

```
ActionController::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash.any_instance.stubs(:user_id).returns(1)
```